# Tangent space definition in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, tangent-line, tangent-spaces

In my Algebraic Geometry course, a tangent space at a point $a$ on a variety was defined as the set of lines $L = \{ a + t \alpha | t \in, k\}$ with intersection multiplicity greater than or equal to 2,  where $k$ is the field which we are working on. I thought I understood the definition in the class but cannot  make sense of it after coming back. For a start how do we define addition on this space so as to make it a vector space? If we think of adding lines as just adding their slopes the problem arises when the same line can be represented by a scalar multiple of the present slope. Can someone help me out here?

PS: Even though I tried to find references for this, most of it uses some definition with sheaves which I am not very familiar with. Is it possible to provide some references for these?( We are presently doing the first chapter in Hartshorne) Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're in a course, you would do well to ask your instructor. Especially since this material isn't covered in the portions of the text you talk about in the post.

Comment: You want to think of it as the set of lines-equipped-with-a-parameterization, not just bare lines; that makes it meaningful to add them. This is a somewhat disguised version of a definition of the Zariski tangent space in terms of derivations.

Comment: Over an algebraic closed field, your affine variety $V$ is the vanishing set of polynomials $f_m\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, for $A\in V$ then $T_A V$ is the set of vectors $B\in k^n$ such that $\forall m,\partial_t f_m(A+tB)|_{t=0} = 0$. It is a vector space. From $d$ coordinates being a transcendental basis of the coordinate ring $k[X]/(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ show $V$ is the vanishing set of $n-d$ polynomials $g_j$, look at their Jacobian matrix $M_{ij}(A) = \partial_{X_i} g_j(A)$, then $T_A V = \ker(M^\top)$ and $A$ is a smooth point if $\det(M^\top M)\ne 0$ in which case $\dim T_A V=d=\dim V$.